# How to decrease the count, when entering numbers or characters into the textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<script>
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit)
{
  var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
  if( field.value.length > maxlimit ) 
  {
    field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
    return false;
  } 
  else 
  {
    countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
  }
}
</script>
<textarea onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',50);"  id="message"></textarea>
<input disabled maxlength="3" size="3" value="50" id="counter">
```

when entering numbers or characters into the textarea, How do I decrease the count?

Comment: what do you mean by "How to decrees the count when press the key few seconds after it did not decrease the count" ?

Comment: This seems to work okay to me... http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/5Y6Kq/

Comment: you want to limit the character in textarea?

Comment: Do you not want to decrease the counter for things like periods, commas, etc.?

Comment: Try my answer .. You will get as you want

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery I'm going to assume you have it loaded...monitor the textarea using on change event: http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('#message').change(function() {
  // do stuff to counter
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit)
{
  var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
  var textfield = document.getElementById(field);
  countfield.value = maxlimit - textfield.value.length;
  if(countfield.value < 0)
  {
    textfield.value = textfield.value.substring(0,maxlimit);
    countfield.value = 0;
  }
}

<textarea onkeyup="textCounter('message','counter',50);"  id="message"></textarea>
<input disabled maxlength="3" size="3" value="50" id="counter">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit)
{
  var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
```

If the controls are in a form (and likely they are) you can use:

```
    var countfield = field.form[field2];
```

.

```
  if( field.value.length > maxlimit ) 
  {
    field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
```

Ouch, that's a bit nasty. Why not just let the user know there are too many characters and leave it up to them to edit the value?

```
    return false;
```

That does nothing at all.

```
  } 
  else 
  {
    countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
  }
}
```

There should be no "else", just write the value and if it's negative, the user will know to trim the number of characters. So your function can be:

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit)
{
    field.form[field2].value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

There is also the [maxlength](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-maxlength-attribute) attribute, which requires no script at all.